# Cakebrew says "Error: Calling 'brew search' with no arguments to output formulae is disabled!"

Tags: homebrew

I am a new macOS user. I just did a fresh install on an A1398 MacBook Pro and upgraded to Big Sur. As I am used to package managers, I decided to investigate Homebrew and Cakebrew to go along with it. I was able to install Homebrew, with no warnings or errors. Then, I installed Cakebrew with the `brew` command.

Upon launching Cakebrew, the "All Formulae" list reports the following error:

> Error: Calling 'brew search' with no arguments to output formulae is disabled! Use 'brew formulae' instead.

The same error occurs if I execute `brew search` on the command-line.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the resolution of this issue by upgrade to v 1.3.  That, I think, makes my answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is from the `brew` command, and Cakebrew is just reporting it. You can see the error if, in Terminal, you do: `brew search`.  I suspect that your Cakebrew has not kept up with changes to the `brew` command.

The version of Cakebrew installed via HomeBrew is version 1.2.5. I have always used that from [Cakebrew](https://www.cakebrew.com) web site. From there you will get version 1.2.7.  Try that.  The "All Formulae" list works for me.

Edit: The question was also asked here [github](https://github.com/brunophilipe/Cakebrew/issues/228). The recommendation is to update to version 1.3.  This fixes the issue.

Comment: I have tried 1.2.5 (via `brew`) and 1.2.7 (via the website). Both have the same error.

Comment: Same problem.
Upgrading Cakebrew to 1.3 work for me :-)
Thanks a lot.